# Applying function to a dataframe with a vector return axis related error?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, apply, similarity

I have the following function, dataframe and vector, why I am getting an error?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def vanilla_vec_similarity(x, y):
  x.drop('request_id', axis=1, inplace=True).values.flatten().tolist()
  y.drop('request_id', axis=1, inplace=True).values.flatten().tolist()
  res = (np.array(x) == np.array(y)).astype(int)
  return res.mean()


test_df = pd.DataFrame({'request_id': [55, 42, 13], 'a': ['x','y','z'], 'b':[1,2,3], 'c': [1.0, -1.8, 19.113]})
test_vec = pd.DataFrame([[123,'x',1.1, -1.8]], columns=['request_id', 'a', 'b', 'c'])

test_df['similarity'] = test_df.apply(lambda x: vanilla_vec_similarity(x, test_vec), axis=1)



---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _get_axis_number(cls, axis)
    367         try:
--> 368             return cls._AXIS_TO_AXIS_NUMBER[axis]
    369         except KeyError:

KeyError: 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _get_axis_number(cls, axis)
    368             return cls._AXIS_TO_AXIS_NUMBER[axis]
    369         except KeyError:
--> 370             raise ValueError(f"No axis named {axis} for object type {cls.__name__}")
    371 
    372     @classmethod

ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type Series
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this code work with the following changes:

```
def vanilla_vec_similarity(x, y):
    x.drop('request_id', axis=1).values.flatten().tolist()
    y.drop('request_id', axis=1).values.flatten().tolist()
    res = (np.array(x) == np.array(y)).astype(int)
    return res.mean()


test_df = pd.DataFrame({'request_id': [55, 42, 13], 'a': ['x','y','z'], 'b':[1,2,3], 'c': [1.0, -1.8, 19.113]})
test_vec = pd.DataFrame([[123,'x',1.1, -1.8]], columns=['request_id', 'a', 'b', 'c'])

test_df['similarity'] = test_df.apply(lambda x: vanilla_vec_similarity(x.to_frame().T, test_vec), axis=1)
```

Explanation:

- Firstly when you do this `test_df.apply(lambda x: vanilla_vec_similarity(x, test_vec), axis=1)` you are passing each
  row as a series (with column names as index of series) to the
  function.
- Code breaks because you are trying to drop column `request_id` as it does not exists.
- Also you don't need to use `inplace=True.`

Or You can just use:

```
test_df['similarity'] = test_df.apply(lambda x: x[1:].eq(pd.Series(test_vec.loc[0])[1:]).mean(), axis=1)
```

Or If you define `test_vec` as `Series` instead of `Dataframe`:

```
test_vec = pd.Series([123,'x',1.1, -1.8], index=['request_id', 'a', 'b', 'c'])
test_df['similarity'] = test_df.apply(lambda x: x[1:].eq(test_vec[1:]).mean(), axis=1)
```

Comment: Why I don't need to use ```inplace=True```? I don't need this column when I calculate similarity. Please explain

Comment: @Muhammad you need to add `x = ` and `y = ` to the first rows of the function.

Comment: I understand but why inplace fails it?

Comment: No, I mean it will drop the column and will continue with the rest of the operations that you have in that line i.e. `.values.flatten().tolist()`. We would have used inplace if all we were doing there is `x.drop('request_id', axis=1, inplace=True)`

Comment: Yes but when I add inplace, it fails the code, why?

Comment: As listed in the documentation `If False, return a copy. Otherwise, do operation inplace and return None.` It fails because it returns None and then you are trying to apply `.values` on something that is essentially `None`. I hope I am able to explain this clearly

Comment: Please read this: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html

Comment: "Code breaks because you are trying to drop column request_id as it does not exists." This is not the reason why code breaks in Steve's code. It breaks because x is a pandas.Series and as such it has only one axis, 0. You could write `x.drop('request_id', inplace=True).values.flatten().tolist()`: in that case the drop would be successful, but it would return `None` as Muhammad said, so applying `values` to it would throw an error.

Comment: I already described that in the first line. I meant that OP's intention is to drop a column which essentially does not exists as it is a series

Comment: So you suggest just doing the ```x=``` and ```y=``` @Simone?

Comment: @Muhammad Sorry I was a bit harsh, the point I was trying to make was quite subtle. I meant that what does not exist is the axis 1, and as a consequence that column does not exist because a Series has no columns (but it does indeed exist as a row index, which is the reason why you could also pass `x` to the function and remove `axis=1` from the drop).

Comment: @Steve Yes, adding that to Muhammad's code should work.

Comment: Another point: using `inplace=True` in this case breakes the code also for another reason. In this way you are deleting in place a column of your dataframe `test_df`. So the function (after an appropriate fix) will work when applied to the first row, but it would throw an error when applied to the second one because now the column you deleted does not exist anymore.

Comment: Because it's a copy of the whole dataframe? Why deleting one column in a specific vector deletes it in the whole dataframe?

Comment: @SteveS plz check the edited answer and let me know if it produces the desired result

Comment: @SteveS The vector you mention points to a row of the dataframe, so it is not clear a priori what happens when you delete a column from it. I tried and in fact it deletes the column from the whole dataframe. In general I would discourage the use of `inplace=True`, because if you don't use it carefully then weird things like this could happen.